# Adding jQuery delete confirmation box in existing hide-function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with hide function which allows me to hide several elements in a page.

The hide-boxes are like:

```
<div class="box">
  <a href='javascript:setHide("Element_1")' class="button element_hide">Hide Box 1</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a href='javascript:setHide("Element_2")' class="button element_hide">Hide Box 2</a>
</div>
```

And the js is:

```
    $('.element_hide').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.box').hide(300);
    });
    function setHide(ObjID) {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      var p_str = "p="+ObjID;
      xmlhttp.open("POST","/hide/",true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send(p_str);
    }
```

Now I want to add a confirmation box; If I click on "hide-box link", I want to display the following message: "Do you really want to hide the box?". So I tried to change the js part to this:

```
    $('.element_hide').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.box').hide(300);
    });
    function setHide(ObjID) {
        if (confirm("Do you really want to hide the box?")) {
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          var p_str = "p="+ObjID;
          xmlhttp.open("POST","/hide/",true);
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          xmlhttp.send(p_str);
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work because the box still disappears even when I click "cancel" (in the confirmation box).

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have two separate event handlers for hiding and for confirmation, and the one for hiding always runs. The first event is set with `href='javascript:setHide("Element_1")'` and the second with jQuery's `$('.element_hide').click`.

Move everything into the common handler:

```
$('.element_hide').click(function() {
  if (confirm("Do you really want to hide the box?")) {
    var xmlhttp

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var ObjID = $(this).data('hide');
    var p_str = "p=" + ObjID;
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "/hide/", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(p_str);

    $(this).closest('.box').hide(300);
  }
});
```

HTML part will become:

```html
<div class="box">
  <a data-hide="Element_1" class="button element_hide">Hide Box 1</a>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <a data-hide="Element_2" class="button element_hide">Hide Box 2</a>
</div>
```

Note, how you can use data attributes (`data-hide="Element_1"`) to pass `ObjID` into event handler.